# Change Response type on Swagger

Tags: swagger, response

How do you change the response content-type on Swagger?

[image]

I tried changing the media type to

```
"content" : {
"text/plain; charset=utf-8" :{ "ABC, XYZ"
 }
```

Results in an error to remove additional properties

Comment: Do you use `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`? Could you post you complete OpenAPI (Swagger) definition file?

Comment: Also check out https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/ if you use `openapi: 3.0.0` or https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-responses/ if you use `swagger: '2.0'`.